# Simple DQL request using Doctrine2 & Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm-postgres

I want to use the query_builder in a Symfony2 FormType, I tried to make a simple request in my Postgresql shema using Doctrine DQL. It return me an error and i don't really understand how fix it :

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "" AS id0 FROM ""
LINE 1: SELECT "0_."id" AS id0 FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."WindFarm" "0_
```

This is the Windfarm class :

```
<?php

namespace Base\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * WindFarm
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="""DATA_WAREHOUSE"".""WindFarm""")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Base\CoreBundle\Repository\WindFarmRepository")
 */
class WindFarm
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Base\CoreBundle\Entity\Turbine", mappedBy="windFarm")
     */
    private $turbines;

    /**
     * @var string $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="""id""", type="string", length=32)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="""DATA_WAREHOUSE"".""WindFarm_id_seq""", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="""name""", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string $alias
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="""alias""", type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $alias;

    /**
     * @var string $location
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="""location""", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var string $sncNbr
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="""sncNbr""", type="string", length=8, nullable=true)
     */
    private $sncNbr;
}
```

The DQL request in the WindFarmRepository:

```
public function getWindFarmsAndTurbines(){

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->select('wft')
                   ->from('BaseCoreBundle:WindFarm', 'wft')
                   ->leftJoin('wft.turbines', 't')
                   ->addSelect('t')
                   ->orderBy('t.alias');

        return $qb;
    }
```

The FormType :

```
<?php

namespace Base\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Base\CoreBundle\Repository\WindFarmRepository;

class TurbineStatusCodeType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('exportBegin', 'date', array('input'  => 'datetime',
                                                   'widget' => 'single_text',
                                                   'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',))
                ->add('exportEnd', 'date', array('input'  => 'datetime',
                                                 'widget' => 'single_text',
                                                 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',))
                ->add('arrayId', 'textarea')
                ->add('turbines', 'entity', array('class' => 'BaseCoreBundle:WindFarm',
                                                             'property' => 'name',
                                                             'multiple' => true,
                                                             'expanded' => true,
                                                   'query_builder' => function(WindFarmRepository $repo){
                                                    return $repo->getWindFarmsAndTurbines();
                                                   }))
                ->add('save', 'submit');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'base_corebundle_turbineStatusCodeType';
    }
}
```

apparently, the problem is situated in the quote, I tried many solutions, but nothing work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your Doctrine annotations are incorrect and have extra double-quotes.

```
@ORM\Column(name="""id""", type="string", length=32)
```

should be

```
@ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=32)
```

and so on

Comment: Thank you Jason, effectively, replace the double-quotes solved my problem !